# Ternary conditional operator: There is no implicit conversion between 'throw' and 'throw' c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, .net-core

I currently have:

```
if (isCritical)
    throw new CriticalException(a, b);
throw new FailException(a, b);
```

I would like to use ternary conditional operator like:

```
isCritical ? throw new CriticalException(a, b) : throw new FailException(a, b);
```

But I get error **There is no implicit conversion between 'throw' and 'throw'**
Does this mean it is not possible to do it like this here or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: you cant use difetent return types on ternary operations, you will need to do an if statement for this, or cast CriticalException and FailException to the same type "Exception" for this to work

Comment: @MestreDosMagros: You seem to be discussing `throw a? b: c` but the question is about `a? throw b: throw c`

Comment: "If a target type of a conditional expression is unknown (for example, when you use the var keyword) or in C# 8.0 and earlier, the type of consequent and alternative must be the same or there must be an implicit conversion from one type to the other". See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: @MestreDosMagros: True, but not applicable here.  `new CriticalException()` has a type.  `throw new CriticalException()` does not.  Throwing the same type in both branches will not solve the problem.

Comment: But this is not allowed by C#. The operation must have to yield an "true" or "false" result for isCritical

Comment: @MestreDosMagros: No... the condition is `bool` but the result type of the ternary can be anything, it is not necessary that the consequent and/or alternative be `true` or `false`.

Comment: @BenVoigt, yes, after reading the docs i realize that :)

Comment: var ex = x ? new Exception("a") : new Exception("b");
throw ex;

Answer (score 5):

You can't use the ternary like that, even if you solve the type problem.

The ternary operator cannot be a standalone statement.  This isn't allowed either:

```
a? f(): g();
```

However, you *can* use the ternary *inside* the operand of `throw`:

```
throw (a? b: c)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code execution will stop in your example for any value of `isCritical` -- therefore the result will never be processed. But if you still want expression syntax / ternary operator, you can use a dummy value like this:

```
var neverGetsAssigned = false ? 0 : isCritical ? throw new CriticalException(a, b) : throw new FailException(a, b);
```